# Mongoose findOne inside loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a `document` `Users` with `storage` property defined as an array of `ObjectId` referenced to other `document` called `Storage`. I'm trying to get a specific user and then return the storage information inside an array.

This is my code:

```
module.exports.storageDetail = function(req, res) {
      User.findOne({'userId': req.user.userId}, 'storages').then(function(data){
        var storageArray = [];

        data.storages.forEach(function(record){
          Storage.findOne({_id: record}, function(err, storage){
            storageArray.push(storage);
          });
        });

        return Promise.all(storageArray);
      }).then(function(storageList){
        res.render('storage_template', {
          storage: storageList
        });
        console.log(storageList);
      });
}
```

But after execution, `storageList` is an empty array.

I'm a newbie to node.js and please let me know if I need to provide more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the main point here is that you need to [`.exec()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-exec) in order to return the Promise. This is why your attempt failed. But there are better approaches syntactically as well.

Instead use [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?v=example) and call [`.exec()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-exec) to return the Promise

```
User.findOne({'userId': req.user.userId}, 'storages').then(function(data){
  var storageArray = data.storages.map(function(id) { 
    return Storage.findOne({_id: id }).exec() 
  });
  return Promise.all(storageArray);
}).then(function(storageList){
  res.render('storage_template', {
    storage: storageList
  });
  console.log(storageList);
});
```

Or instead use [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) with [`.find()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-find) where the method returns an array and the operator allows you to specify an array of things to match:

```
User.findOne({'userId': req.user.userId}, 'storages').then(function(data){
  return Storage.find({ "_id": { "$in": data.storages } }).exec();
}).then(function(storageList){
  res.render('storage_template', {
    storage: storageList
  });
  console.log(storageList);
});
```

It also basically looks like you could instead simply use [`.populate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)

```
User.findOne({'userId': req.user.userId}, 'storages')
  .populate('storages')
  .then(function(data) {
    res.render('storage_template', {
      storage: data.storages
    });
    console.log(data.storages);
  });
```

But it's not clear in your question if these are actually defined as references to the `Storage` model or not.

Also see [Queries are not Promises](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html) in the mongoose documentation.

Comment: Both solutions are working great! Can you also please tell me how can I use the first one with ES5?

Comment: @Valip I replaced the fat arrow syntax with a regular function for you. The main point here is the `.exec()` to get the Promise.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using mongoose then you can use `.populate()` to get your `storages` information details from `Storage` collection.

can try this one

```
module.exports.storageDetail = function(req, res) {
  User.findOne({'userId': req.user.userId}, 'storages')
    .populate('storages')
    .exec(function (err, storageList) {
      if (err) return handleError(err);
      console.log(storageList);
      res.render('storage_template', {
        storage: storageList
      });
    });
}
```

for using this `.populate()` ensure first in your `User` model you added `ref` filed for `storages`

like:

```
storages: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Storage' }]
```

Answer (score 0):

//do npm install lodash

```
const _ = require('lodash');
 module.exports.storageDetail = function(req, res) {
  User.findOne({'userId': req.user.userId}, 'storages').then(function(data){
    var storageArray = [];
    let queries =  _.map(data.storages, (record)=>{
     return Storage.findOne({_id: record}, function(err, storage){
        storageArray.push(storage);
      });
})

    return Promise.all(queries);
  }).then(function(storageList){
    res.render('storage_template', {
      storage: storageList
    });
    console.log(storageList);
  });
}
```